# Solving a system of linear equations to find two eigenvectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So I have
\begin{align*}
x - 2y + z & = 0 \\
-2x + 4y - 2z & = 0 \\
x - 2y + z & = 0
\end{align*}

I know I need to find two eigenvectors for the eigenspace with eigenvalue 2 as I know the matrix is diagonalizable and I've already found the eigenvector for the eigenspace with eigenvalue 8...

I can't seem to solve this. Please help!

Comment: I need the solutions for this system of equations as I can't work it out for some reason.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you meant(1,-2,1) in the first part of the WA command? Yeah, I get it when y = 0, z = -x and that's a solution? And if z=0, x=2y and if x=0, z = 2y?

Answer (score 2):

$$ \begin{align*}
x - 2y + z & = 0 \\
-2x + 4y - 2z & = 0 \\
x - 2y + z & = 0 
\end{align*} $$

$$ \implies  \begin{align*}
x - 2y + z & = 0 \\
0 & = 0 \\
0 & = 0.
\end{align*}$$

So you have two free variables. Assuming $y=t, z=s,\, t,s\in \mathbb{R} $, then the solution is given by

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
       x  \\
       y\\
       z\end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix}
       2t-s  \\
       t\\
       s\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
       2t  \\
       t\\
       0\end{bmatrix} +  \begin{bmatrix}
       -s  \\
       0\\
       s\end{bmatrix} = t\begin{bmatrix}
       2  \\
       1\\
       0\end{bmatrix} +  s\begin{bmatrix}
       -1  \\
       0\\
       1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Can you see the two eigenvectors now?